# Is there a way to get files from my client's personal s3 accounts via 0auth just like Google Drive or DropBox?

Tags: amazon-s3, oauth-2.0, cloud

Use case: In our application, we must establish connections to multiple cloud storage services, including Google Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive, and Amazon S3. The goal is to automate the retrieval of documents from our clients' individual accounts and subsequently extract text from these documents. I have successfully achieved this functionality with the first three services mentioned.

However, I'm now exploring the possibility of securely implementing this process with Amazon S3, considering that S3 is primarily an infrastructure-level storage service and not designed for consumer-oriented use. Do you have any guidance on how to accomplish this securely?